# Map a resultset to a Nested java object

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to use `ResultSetExtractor` to map the `ResultSet` to a java object, but I just can't figure the way to map it correctly. The data is of the following format:

[image: Data format]

To understand better it can be simplified as:

[image: Data format simplified]

One JOB INSTANCE can have one or more Steps entries.
This is the POJO class each job entry is to be mapped to-

**(My ask is for the `ResultSetExtractor` to return a list of `JobDetails`)**

```
public class JobDetails {
    private long jobInstanceId;
    private long jobExecutionId;
    private String jobStatus;
    private List<StepDetails> steps;
}
```

```
public class StepDetails {
    private long stepExecutionId;
    private String stepName;
    private String stepStatus;
}
```

In JSON terms it would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "jobInstanceId": 1,
        "jobExecutionId": 1,
        "jobExecutionStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "steps": [
            {
                "stepExecutionId" : 1,
                "stepName" : "automatedStep0",
                "stepStatus" : "COMPLETED"
            },
            {
                "stepExecutionId" : 2,
                "stepName" : "automatedStep1",
                "stepStatus" : "COMPLETED"
            },
            {
                "stepExecutionId" : 3,
                "stepName" : "automatedStep2",
                "stepStatus" : "COMPLETED"
            }
        
        ]
    },
    {
        "jobInstanceId": 2,
        "jobExecutionId": 2,
        "jobExecutionStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "steps": [
            {
                "stepExecutionId" : 4,
                "stepName" : "automatedStep0"
                "stepStatus" : "COMPLETED"
            },
            {
                "stepExecutionId" : 5,
                "stepName" : "automatedStep1"
                "stepStatus" : "COMPLETED"
            },
            {
                "stepExecutionId" : 6,
                "stepName" : "automatedStep2"
                "stepStatus" : "COMPLETED"
            }
        ]
        
    }
    .....
]
```

For now the following logic works. But it's not very clean. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner and more efficient approach:

```
    public List<JobDetails> fetchJobs() {

        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        return jdbcTemplate.query(query, params , rs -> {


            List<JobDetails> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
            List <StepDetails> stepList = new ArrayList<>();
            JobDetails jobDetails=JobDetails.builder().build();
            long prevInstanceId=0;

            while(rs.next()) {
                
                long currentInstanceId = rs.getLong("JOB_INSTANCE_ID");
                boolean isNewInstance = currentInstanceId != prevInstanceId;    //    while iterating, check if it is a new JobInstance i.e row's id != prev row's id
                prevInstanceId = currentInstanceId;

                if(!rs.isFirst() && (isNewInstance || rs.isLast())) {    //   at the beginning of a new JobInstance, set the stepList into the JobDetails object and add the jobDetails to the final list to be returned
                    jobDetails.setSteps(stepList);
                    jobList.add(jobDetails);
                }

                if(rs.isFirst() || isNewInstance) {    //  at the beginning of a new Job Instance, create a new JobDetails object, and a new StepDetails ArrayList

                    jobDetails = JobDetails.builder()
                                            .jobInstanceId(rs.getLong("JOB_INSTANCE_ID"))
                                            .jobExecutionId(rs.getLong("JOB_EXECUTION_ID"))
                                            .jobExecutionStatus(rs.getString("JOB_STATUS"))
                                            .build();
                    stepList = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                StepDetails step = new StepDetails(rs.getLong("STEP_EXECUTION_ID"), rs.getString("STEP_NAME"), rs.getString("STEP_SATUS"));    //   for each row, create a StepDetails object and add it to the list
                stepList.add(step);

            }


            return jobList;
        });

    }
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Did you already try something? Sharing that might make it easier to see where you are actually got stuck.
To be a bit more helpful: I think it might make sense to separate the extraction of the result and transformation into the desired structure.

Comment: Is your stuff in a spreadsheet, is it inside sql server? What's the schema like if it's inside sql server? What have you tried doing already?

Comment: @DaleK - My bad. The sql data was a bit too much for me to format into a table using |'s and -'s. Point noted though.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt I've added my solution in the question. But its not a very clean approach.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz The data I showed is returned by a sql query executed in SQL Server. I just formatted it in a speadsheet for better readability. Also edited my solution in the question.

Comment: If you are using spring boot why not just use https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa and let that handle the fetching.